# Grails hangs at startup

Tags: grails, groovy, activemq-classic

When I run grails it hangs after "finished spring security config.". I change "error" to "all" in Config.groovy and found that it hangs at:

```
2016-04-08 18:13:45,625 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG spring.OptimizedAutowireCapableBeanFactory  - Finished creating instance of bean 'amq:transportConnector#4b67ee9b'
2016-04-08 18:13:45,627 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor  - Invoking init method on bean 'org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService#0': public void org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.autoStart() throws java.lang.Exception
```

Using the following dependencies:

```
dependencies {         
// specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.          
compile 'org.apache.activemq:activemq-core:5.7.0'         
compile 'org.apache.xbean:xbean-spring:3.5'        
runtime("org.apache.camel:camel-netty:2.9.4")
........
..............
}
```

and plugins:

```
compile ":jms:1.3"
compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-websocket:1.0.0"
........etc.........
```

Tried various solutions but didn't work.

Comment: Without a lot more information (such as your AMQ and JMS settings in your `Config.groovy`) it's going to be hard to say what the exact problem is. It looks like your AMQ plugin isn't starting up and JMS is waiting for the broker to be available.

Comment: What's your grails version?